# HTML5 video - multiple video files

Tags: html, video, video-streaming

Is it possible to playing multiple video files (pieces of single video) in the same player with common timeline? This must look like single video. It is posible?

I can't glue fragments in the signle video because of disk space problem. I'd like stream multiple files sequentially by request of user. 
The requirement of HTML5 is from iPad/Android 4.1+ compatibility

Answer (score 1):

It's a little hard. Can two Video traces be played with same common timeline. Camtasia Recorder 8 could transcribe videos you could have a try.  [Macgo Mac Blu-ray Player](http://www.macblurayplayer.com/features.htm)  cannot support this function now. I used it for several years. But it could open 2 videos with two different windows. If you tried and success, please let me know. Haha..